# delete table row by name

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dropzone.js

I'm using `dropzone.js` to store image files to a folder. Problem is, all uploaded image previews are only shown within the `dropzone field` as long as there is no refresh or switching to an other link on the same page so those images can only be removed right after they are uploaded (please correct me if I'm wrong here).

Due to this circumstance I had an idea by saving informations (eg. file name, size, link, type and more) along with the upload to `MySQL` database and later make a query for a table output so I'm able to delete the certain image file somewhen later from the table row.

[image]

By clicking the trash can (watch attached image) normally the name from the file should be fetched by `jQuery` and later sent by `AJAX` to `PHP` so the row can be deleted from database and the file is unlinked from the folder. Somehow it works well by `ID` but not `name`. I cannot see a possible mistake here thus I need your help. It's really important that I need a `NAME` to be fetched by `jQuery` not `ID`. Does it even work this way? If so, how? If not, how?

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover droplist">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>filename</th>
                        <th>size[bytes]</th>
                        <th>image</th>
                        <th>type</th>
                        <th>created_at</th>
                        <th>delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

<?php 
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM file_upload ORDER BY id");
$result = $statement->execute();
$count = 1;
while($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr name="'.$row['name'].'">';
        echo "<td>".$count++."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['size']."</td>";
        // echo '<td><a href="'.$row['link'].'">'.$row['link'].'</a></td>';
        echo "<td>".$row['type']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".date('d.m.Y H:i:s',strtotime($row['date']))."</td>";
        echo '<td><a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-trash" ></i></a></td>';
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

the `dropzonelist.js`:

```
$('table.droplist td a.delete').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).parent().parent().prop('name');
    var data = 'name=' + name ;
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    // alert(name),

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_dropfile.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response) { 
            //...whatever
```

btw, alert(name) keeps saying: undefined! IDK

the `PHP` script:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $file = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    die;
} 

// sql to delete a record
$filedel = "DELETE FROM file_upload WHERE name='$file'";
if ($pdo->exec($filedel)) {
    echo "(image)file successfully erased!";
}
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/anydaynow/gallery/samples/' . $file);
?>
```

Comment: could you do me a favor and add the HTML that results from your PHP code somewhere? I see that you've added the PHP code that generates the HTML, but without data for me to use to fill out that loop I'd basically be playing a guessing game with myself.

Comment: Only the echo is returned by the PHP script and sent as an success alert to the JS file. That's it. Everything else is processed in the back.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the data, you need to use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
var name = $(this).parent().parent().attr('name');
```

You can use `prop()` only to those [tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp) that are supported for `<tr>` like `class` and `id`, which in your case, where you use `name`, is not supported. While `attr()` can be used for different unsupported tags.

---

#### Another method:

One approach is to assign a new tag on your `<a>` directly, instead of going through the parent twice:

```
echo '<td><a class="delete" href="#" data-artname="'.$row['name'].'">...
```

so, instead of getting the name using:

```
var name = $(this).parent().parent().attr('name');
```

you can get the corresponding name data using:

```
var name = $(this).attr('data-artname');
```

You can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/jdqagn00/) for an example.

---

<sup>You still need to consider the answer and recommendation of @e4c5</sup>

Comment: yes, now it works fine! thumbs up! I thought .prop() would be the same such as .attr() and .attr() is meanwhile obsolete and not used anymore. I once again have to check the differences between both methods. Very nice, you solved this freaky issue.

Comment: @what_me - if an answer helped you, you can tick the corresponding check icon on to the left of the answer or up-vote the answer that best helped you.

Answer (score 1):

### Javascript error

There is a problem in your javascript. This is wrong.

```
var data = 'name=' + name ;
```

Well sometimes it will work but when the filename contains non alphanumeric characters, even a space this will break. For example if the file name is `hello world.jpg` it will be sent to the server as just that but the server wants it as `hello+world.jpg` You should instead do

```
 var data = {'name': name }
```

### PHP Error

This is also wrong.

```
 $filedel = "DELETE FROM file_upload WHERE name='$file'";
```

Special characters will break this and worse it might lead to sql injection. Fix as

```
$filedel = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM file_upload WHERE name=:file");
$filedel->execute(array(":file"=>$file));
```

Comment: Even by altering the JS code to var data = {'name': name } it keeps saying : Undefined! It seems no value (name from the image file) can be fetched for some reason. That's odd! Any idea what else could be wrong?

Comment: in the code you have posted there isn't a table with a droplist class

Comment: why you don't add the name directly to the `<a>` tag is a mystery to me!

Comment: @e4c5 - and that is what I recommend on my answer :(

Comment: By the way we have moved a long way away from the original question. That had two issues which I helped you to solve. The undefined variable is something else all together. Please be so kind as to accept this question and post another question if you continue to have trouble with that

Comment: @LoganWayne yes you are right. +1 from me. I didn't notice that issue while addresseing the two bigger issues